# Duplicate Entry when updating a specific datetime column

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `special_offers` with the following columns: 
`id`, `old_price`, `new_price`, `redeemed_at`

`id` is an auto incremented primary key.

When I create a row the `redeemed_at` column is set to `NULL`

I have created a new row with `old_price = 20` and `new_price = 10`

So currently I have a row which looks like this: |`1`|`20`|`10`|`NULL`|

When I run the following query: `UPDATE special_offers SET redeemed_at = NOW() WHERE id = 1`

It all goes well and update the row.

Then, I change the `redeemed_at` row back to NULL and run the same query again, and I get the following error: `#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`

I can change any other column and it won't give me the error, only on this specific `redeemed_at`.

Any ideas what's up?

Comment: Really doubtful. Can you attach a single screen shot of the existing record and the "update" statement you executed? If the screen is taken on "MySQL Command Line" interface that would be great.

Comment: You can give the table structure and queries you executed.

Comment: Please post query which gave this error because it seems your update query can not give such error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on a `trigger` that was inserting a log on that table.

It logged the table as is, including the primary key and upon 2nd logging it gave the duplicate. The error failed to mention the table.